# Mysterious Network Client

Tags: security

When I look at my data network with Windows Explorer My Network Places I see all of my network clients and printers.

However, I am seeing an unknown client called `tsclient`. When I click on it I cannot see anything.

Normally in "My Network Places" I can right click on propertys and get the status of the device including the IP address.

When I right click I do not get any "property" drop-down.  I vpn into the data router and look at all the IP addresses and they all appear to be accounted for.

Anyone know what this is?  Any way to better get information on just where is this device is and what is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tsclient is in fact related to TS/RDS. It provides an alternate mechanism for accessing resources on the client machine from the host that the client machine is connected to via the RDP/RDC client software (mstsc.exe). This is not limited to servers that have the TS or RDS role installed but is available on any host that has the TS or RDS service running. When connecting to a host via the RDP/RDC client you can choose to redirect local resources to the remote session, such as drives and printers, these show up in Windows Explorer and in the Printers folder. The `\\tsclient` object allows you to access these same resources via a UNC path, such as `\\tsclient\c` as opposed to seeing them in Windows Explorer as "C on TsClientComputerName". It's perfectly normal but if you're worried about it you can disable the TS/RDS service on your servers or disable resource rdirection so that local resources on the TS/RDS client can't be accessed from the host that the client is connected to.

Comment: This makes total sense since I was using remote desktop to access the server.  I had just put together this server so I was concerned to see this unknown network client.  Now that I know I will not change anything.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Glad to help. Take note that if you are not redirecting local resources via RDP then the tsclient will be empty when you browse it.

Answer (score 3):

`tsclient` is how you access your host PC when you are remote desktoped into another PC somewhere else.

Are you actually seeing this on your local PC, or are you using remote desktop into another PC when you're seeing this?

If it's the latter, this can safely be ignored.

Comment: Hello Mark, actually I was using Remote Desktop to access the server.  If tsclient is part of RDC then I guess I am ok.

Comment: @user - yes, then that network object is just your local PC that you used to connect with RDP. It is safe to ignore. Nobody else will see it, only you.

Answer (score -1):

tsclient sounds like something to do with Terminal Server. Try disabling Terminal Services on the server and see if it goes away.

Comment: Hello nocache, I was using RDC to access the server remotely.  Thanks for the input.  It looks like I am ok.